# Failed to sync Gradle project in Android studio version 1.5.1 API 23

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I keep coming up with this error "Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-15' in: C:\Android\sdk1 Open Android SDK Manager." I recently installed Android Studio 1.4 and then upgraded to version 1.5.1 with API 23. How can I solve this error?

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' android {
    compileSdkVersion 15 buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pg.com.dwu.app_inventry" minSdkVersion 15 targetSdkVersion 19 versionCode 1 versionName "1.0"
    } buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your build.gradle for the app.

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pg.com.dwu.app_inventry"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: It's better to edit your original question so you can format it as code.  This is hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely post your build.gradle so others might be able to help figure out the problem.

I think this solution has probably been posted elsewhere, but...

A logical step is to follow what Android Studio is suggesting: Open Android SDK Manager.

Menu > Tools > Android > SDK Manager

[screenshot of Android SDK Manager Android 6.0 (23) installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPJNS.png)

Then go to your build.gradle (Module: app) and make sure you have the compileSdkVersion set to the same version as what you installed in your SDK Manager.

[sdk version in build.gradle matching SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaneN.png)

If these aren't matching up, then you should change your compileSdkVersion to match the Manager.

Then 1) Rebuild the project and 2) Run it to see if it works.

If that doesn't solve the problem it could *possibly* be that your project is pointing to a location that's different from where your SDK is actually installed. You can see this back in the SDK Manager dialogue where it says Android SDK Location.

Change the location here if that's not where you installed it.